# Removing an object from List (Of T)

Tags: vb.net, list, visual-studio-2012, methods

I'm not able to remove an object from my List (of contact)

Here are my fields:

```
Public Class Contact
'Things to remember 
Private m_firstName As String = String.Empty
Private m_lastName As String = String.Empty 
Private m_address As Address
```

My list:

```
Public Class ContactManager
Private m_contactRegistry As List(Of Contact)

Public Sub New()
    m_contactRegistry = New List(Of Contact)()
End Sub
```

My method in ContactManger Class. **Here I'm getting error "Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to Assignment.Contact"** on the index

```
Public Function DeleteContact(index As Integer) As Boolean


    m_contactRegistry.Remove(index)

    Return True
End Function
```

My delete button method on my Main class:

```
Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click

        'listResults is my listbox

        Dim list = listResults.SelectedIndex

'm_contact is an object of the Contact class
        m_contacts.DeleteContact(list)
        UpdateGUI()
    End Sub
```

The problem is that I don't know how to do the method DeleteContact(index As Integer) without getting an error. Do you guys have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an index, you need [`RemoveAt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than `Remove()`